# Best Practice: AWS ftp with file processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp, amazon-sqs

I'm looking for some direction on an AWS architictural decision. My goal is to allow users to ftp a file to an EC2 instance and then run some analysis on the file. My focus is to build this in as much a service-oriented way as possible.. and in the future scale it out for multiple clients where each would have there own ftp server and processing queue with no co-mingling of data.

Currently I have a dev EC2 instance with vsftpd installed and a node.js process running Chokidar that is continuously watching for new files to be dropped. When that file drops I'd like for another server or group of servers to be notified to get the file and process it.

Should the ftp server move the file to S3 and then use SQS to let the pool of processing servers know that it's ready for processing? Should I use SQS and then have the pool of servers ssh into the ftp instance (or other approach) to get the file rather than use S3 as a intermediary? Are there better approaches?

Any guidance is very much appreciated. Feel free to school me on any alternate ideas that might save money at high file volume.

Answer (score 3):

I'd segregate it right down into small components.

- Load balancer
- FTP Servers in scaling group
- Daemon on FTP Servers to move to S3 and then queue a job
- Processing servers in scaling group

This way you can scale the ftp servers if necessary, or scale the processing servers (on SQS queue length or processor utilisation).  You may end up with one ftp server and 5 processing servers, or vice versa - but at least this way you only scale at the bottleneck.

The other thing you may want to look at is DataPipeline - which (whilst not knowing the details of your job) sounds like it's tailor made for your use case.

S3 and queues are cheap, and it gives you more granular control around the different components to scale as appropriate.  There are potentially some smarts around wildcard policies and IAM you could use to tighten the data segregation too.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally I would try to process the file on the server that it is currently placed.
This will save a lot of network traffic and CPU load.

However if you want one of the servers to be like reverse proxy and to load balance between farm of servers, then I will notify the server with http call that the file has arrived. I would made the file available via ftp since you already has working vsftp that will not be a problem and will include the file ftp url in the http call, so the server that will do the processing can get the file and start working on it immediately.

This way you will save money by not using any extra S3 or SQS or any other additional services.

If the farm of servers are made of equal type of servers, then the algorithm for distributing the load should be RoundRobin if the servers are with different capacity then the load distribution should be made according to the server performance.

For example if server ONE has 3 times more performnce then server THREE and server TWO has 2 times better performance than server THREE, then you can do:

```
1: Server ONE - forward 3 request
2: Server TWO - forward 2 request
3: Server THREE - forward 1 request
4: GOTO 1
```

Ideally there should be feedback from the serves that report the current load so the load-balancer knows who is the best candidate for the next request instead of using hard-coded algorithms, since probably the requests do not need exactly equal amount of resources to be processed, but this start looking like [Map-Reduce paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) and is out of the scope ... at least for the begining. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with S3, you could use [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) to mount S3 bucket as a local filesystem on your FTP and processing servers. Then you could do the usual file operations (e.g.: get the notification when a file was created / modified).

Answer (score 1):

As well as RioFS [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) utilizes FUSE to provide a filesystem that is (*virtual locally*) mountable; s3fs-fuse is currently [well-maintained](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/commits/master).

In contrast the `Filesystem Abstraction for S3, HDFS and normal filesystem`
[swineherd-fs](https://github.com/infochimps-labs/swineherd-fs) allows to have a different (*locally virtual*) approach:

`All filesystem abstractions implement the following core methods, based on standard UNIX functions, and Ruby's File class`  [...].

As the 'local abstraction layer' has been `Only thoroughly tested on Ubuntu Linux` i'd personally go for a more mainstream/solid/less experimental stack, i.e.:

- a (sandboxed) [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) for
  FTP transfers
- (optionally) [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) for filesystem changes and finally
- trigger
  [middleman-s3_sync](https://github.com/fredjean/middleman-s3_sync) to do the cloud lift (or synchronize all by itself).

Alternatively, and more experimental, there are some github projects that might fit it:

- [s3-ftp](https://github.com/turbovote/s3-ftp): FTP server front-end
  that forwards all uploads to an S3 bucket (Clojure)
- [ftp-to-s3](https://github.com/jpf/ftp-to-s3): An FTP server that
  uploads every file it receives to S3 (Python)
- [ftp-s3](https://github.com/vlad003/ftp-s3): FTP frontend to S3 in Python.

Last but not least i do recommend using donationware [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) if on OSX - a comfortable (and very FTP-like) client interfacing S3 directly. For Windows there is a (*PRO* optional) freeware named [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/).